# Determine if a view is presented inside a popover

Tags: swift, swiftui, popover

I have a view which presents in a popover if the size class is regular, and as a sheet, if size class is compact (standard system presentation behavior). In this view, I have a navigation view. I’d like to only display a “Done” toolbar item if the view is presented as a sheet, but not if presented in a popover.

In UIKit, this is very easy to accomplish, but in SwiftUI, I don’t see any environment value that describes the presentation of the view.

I saw suggestions to look at the `horizontalSizeClass` environment value, but that doesn’t work, because the view is presented with a compact size class inside the popover.

Here is my view:

```swift
struct SettingsView: View {
    fileprivate let internalSettings = SettingsViewInternal()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            internalSettings
                .navigationTitle("Settings")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button("Reset") {
                            internalSettings.reset()
                        }
                    }
                    //This gets called twice, first time with a standard size class,
                    //then with compact size class when the popover presents its content.
                    if sizeClass == .compact {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Done") {
                                self.dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I present the popover like this:

```swift
Button {
    settingsPresented = true
} label: {
    Image("gears")
}
.popover(isPresented: $settingsPresented) {
    SettingsView()
}
```

Comment: Instead of implicit detection (which might be not state in different OS version) I would inject that info directly into init from parent (say some `enum Mode` or bool `dismissible`), because parent knows how it presents this view. Thus the condition becomes trivial.

Comment: If the SwiftUI view has access to the presenter like UIKit has: Check the size class of the presenting view (or view controller).

Comment: @Asperi But isn’t that just moving the problem to the parent view? I have no idea how to know what presentation mode will be chosen there too? Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know how your parent presents this view... how does it?

Comment: @Asperi I’ve updated the question with the code I use to present the popover.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario a possible solution is to track global `horizontalSizeClass` instead of local (which by Apple's doc depends on many things), and inject it into some (say `AppState`) environment object that can be transferred into any presentation.

So it could look like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass

    var body: some View {
       SomeTopView()
         .onAppear {
            appState.sizeClass = sizeClass
         }
         .onChange(of: sizeClass) {
            appState.sizeClass = $0
         }
         .environmentObject(appState)  // << for all view hierarchy !!
    }
}

// ...

    Button {
        settingsPresented = true
    } label: {
        Image("gears")
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $settingsPresented) {
        SettingsView()
          .environmentObject(appState) // << should be injected explicitly !!
    }

// ...

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

// ...

    if appState.sizeClass == .compact {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a method similar to what Asperi suggests, but within the same view, using onAppear() to detect things. I didn't bother to publish it everywhere. I had trouble using the Toolbar, so just put the buttons at the top manually...

```
struct MyPopoverView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
  
  @State private var isPopover: Bool = true
  
  var body : some View {
    if !isPopover {
      Button(action: {
        dismiss()
      }) {
        Text("Dismiss")
      }
    }

    // ... rest of view content

  }
  .onAppear {
    if horizontalSizeClass == .compact && UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
      isPopover = true
    } else {
      isPopover = false
  }
}
```